# React: update a field value based on another field in dynamically generated form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find out the "proper" way to do the following in React:

- I have a form with two fields, `url` and `title`.
- Whenever `url`'s value changes, I make an API call to [Embedly](http://embed.ly/) to retrieve metadata about the link.
- Once the metadata has been retrieved, I want to update the `title` field with the result.

The difficulty here is that the `url` and `title` fields are not in the same component. Here's the basic structure of the form (I'm using [Formsy](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react)):

```
<Formsy.Form onSubmit={this.submitForm} onChange={this.updateState} ref="form">
  {fields.map(field => <FormComponent 
    name={field.name}
    type={field.type}
    value={field.value}
  />)}
  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</Formsy.Form>
```

As you can see, the form loops over an array of fields and calls a generic `<FormComponent/>` component for each of them, which is basically a big `switch` that then calls the appropriate [Formsy Component](https://github.com/twisty/formsy-react-components) based on the field's `type`.

The logic for querying Embedly is already working inside the component for the `url` field, but I'm not sure if there's a way to accomplish what I want while still using the default `Input` component for `title`?

Comment: This is one reason I switched to [react-redux-form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form). It maintains "models" in Redux, such as a "website" model that consists of a url and title. And all I have to do is slap an `onChange` or `onBlur` on an input field like url, which dispatches an action to make an API call, and once that returns, I do `dispatch(actions.change('website.title', fetchedTitle))` which automagically changes the title input to said value (no matter where it is), since it's a controlled input being fed a value straight from Redux.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to think I'm building my own, worse mini-Redux. But at least it's helping me understand why Redux can be useful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Edit: thanks to Dan I was able to come up with a better solution for step 4 and after]**

So here's the solution I came up with. I have no clue if it's the best pattern or not, but at least so far it seems to work.

**Step 1**: add a `addToPrefilledValues` method to the `<Form/>` component that takes a property and adds it to the `prefilledValues` object on that component's state.

**Step 2**: add `addToPrefilledValues` to the form component's `context` so that the method is passed on to all child components (note: I could also pass it as a prop but context seems easier to pass it on to grandchild components).

**Step 3**: make my `<URLField/>` component call `addToPrefilledValues` whenever it receives new metadata from Embedly:

```
this.context.addToPrefilledValues({title: result.title, body: result.description});
```

**Step 4** **[Wrong, see below]**: in the `<TitleField/>` component's `shouldComponentUpdate` method, watch for changes to the context and update the field's value (if it's empty):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {

  const nextTitle = nextContext.prefilledValues && nextContext.prefilledValues.title;
  const currentTitle = this.context.prefilledValues && this.context.prefilledValues.title;

  if (!!nextTitle && nextTitle != currentTitle && !this.input.getValue()) {
    this.input.setValue(nextTitle);
  }

  return true;
}
```

**Step 4 (better)**: whenever the form changes, store all of the form's values in a `currentValue` object on the form's state.

**Step 5**: Look at:

1. the original value of the field (i.e. in the database), as passed through `this.props`).
2. the current value being typed in the field, as found in `this.state.currentValue`.
3. the prefilled value generated by the Embedly API call, as found in `this.state.prefilledValue`.

Figure out which one is correct (i.e. if the user hasn't entered anything in the field prefill it, if not don't) and pass that on to the form field child component.

This achieves the desired result:

- `<URLField/>` and `<TitleField/>` don't have to know about or communicate with each other.
- `<Form/>` doesn't have to know about `<URLField/>` or `<TitleField/>` either.

As @ffxsam suggested though, I should probably just use Redux Form…

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate()` should only serve as a rendering hint. Don't put side effects or app logic there, it is pretty much guaranteed to break randomly in future React versions. It should be pure.

Comment: Tangentially Redux Form and React Redux Form are two different projects, I think @ffxsam was referring to the other one. They have rather different APIs.